# CSS won't apply when linking to HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this webpage (index.html):

[image]

When I click on the 1st image, Management Guides. I want it to get me to my second page (guide.html) - that has its own CSS file. I do it like this: `<a href="guide.html"><img src="managemant-guides.jpg" /></a>`

The second one looks like this when I load it separately:
[image]

However, when I click through the link It looks like this: 
[image]

To make it look as it should I have to refresh the page.

Here's the header of index.html

```
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">      
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>       
     <link href="css/thumbnail-gallery.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    <script src="js/jquery.fullscreen-popup.js"></script>
```

And here's the one for guide.html:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

I guess I could make a refresh script to run onLoad, but I wonder why this happens.

Comment: <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" ></script>      what does this mean

Comment: Why are you using a different css file for your guide.html page? can't you just use appropriate classes and IDs and have all the style in one single css file? this is even better for overall performance of the website

Comment: ...There is no `<link>` declaration for the CSS on guide.html. What is the file name for the CSS for guide.html?

Comment: That's a CSS file from bootstrap. @Nick, the page just came like this, nwo I have to make it work, don't have much of a choice. What I found out is that the onload JS event won't execute the 1st time I enter the page via the link, it's like it's not refreshing it but only showing it.

Comment: There is a link for it, right at the bottom: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> It's a different name, I did it on porpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can google for "dynamic load css", but the best thing would be to just have one css that styles the whole website. Then when you load a page dynamically, the style is already set for it. That will give your website better performance.

Comment: Yes, I can only agree with you, I'm aware of the performance, however it's not my call. If it was all done by me I would just remake the whole css and markup, but that's why I came over here. Ill google that, thank you.